# How do I capture an audit trail of changes made to a view?

Tags: 7, views

What would be the best way for me to log any administrative changes that might have been made on a view? E.g. a new filter added or a field removed. The audit entry should include a user stamp and a time stamp and the change that was made. Doesn't look like any of the conventional options seem to capture this information.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to save your view in code and add version control system ([Git](https://git-scm.com/), SVN) to your project. Every time when you will change the view you will need to update feature with this view and commit your changes into version control system. Then you will have a history of changes

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but this would not enable me to see who made the change and when?

Comment: In the version control history of commits you can see the date of commit, author and code difference.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that's not going to work for me, this would necessitate that the user be development savvy enough to generate the feature and version control it. I was looking at something that would be more CMS centric and use information from the CMS itself e.g. the user login details.